# SOLR suggester return values

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I have implemented a SOLR suggester to search for names (firstname, middlename, lastname). The data for the names is obtained from a database and is stored in *name* field in SOLR.

An eg. of data would be: name : TOM,JASON,SMITH
If there is no middle name, the data would be: name : TOM,,FORD

The suggester doesn't not return value if I search for TOM FORD. It works fine if I search for TOM JASON.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">name</str>
            <str name="weightField">name</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="storeDir">fuzzy_suggestions</str>            
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>
```

The field is configured as following in schema.xml

```
<field name="name" type="text_exact_fuzzy" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_exact_fuzzy" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Is there  a way to make the suggester to return the values where the middle name does not exist?

One way to search is by including the commas in the search string eg. TOM,,FORD. That works, but I am trying to make it work without the commas.

Comment: try by changing the classictokenizer to standard tokenizer

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Tried that but no success.